# Page method call blocks request

Tags: asp.net, pagemethods

We have a page where we use javascript to asynchronously call page methods and update the UI.  If a user clicks on a link on the page before all the async calls complete the browser does not initiate the get  until they all complete.  At least in IE 11 anyhow.  Is there any way around that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASP.NET serializes requests for the same `Session` - to protect `Session` bag against simultaneous writes. To make requests for the same `Session` processed in parallel, page has to be marked as Session-ReadOnly by adding `EnableSessionState="ReadOnly"` to the `Page` directive.

Comment: That's great.  And the page responds so much faster!